# Symfony Doctrine two keys for different purposes, one AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to Symfony and Doctrine and using the latest versions, am trying to create a Model with two key fields (attributes) for different purposes. $id is not the Primary Key but is AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL/MariaDB. $key is string length=100 mapped to CHAR[100] and is the primary key and @ORM\Id. Even though this is what I'm trying to do, I don't think it's a supported configuration. I want to be able to merge() using `key` but also want to have the AI column for references (joining) because in part as I think it will have better performance, and even if not I want it anyway :) The thing is the data source which I use to populate may send multiple objects with the same `key` in which case I want them to persist to the same record, the last object the last to update the db, no duplicate `key`s.

I read somewhere, to use the DB implementation of AI and on non primary key, I may have to write a custom Hydrator. I have little idea what files to create and where to put them, and what mapping I have to do, or how exactly to do it. Hope someone can help.

```
<?php
// src/Entity/View.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ViewRepository")
 */
class View
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="created_by")
     */
    private $created_by;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="updated_by")
     */
    private $updated_by;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", name="id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, name="`key`")
     */
    private $key;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json", name="`value`")
     */
    private $value;


    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->created_by;
    }

    public function setCreatedBy($value)
    {
        $this->created_by = $value;
    }

    public function getUpdatedBy()
    {
        return $this->updated_by;
    }

    public function setUpdatedBy($value)
    {
        $this->updated_by = $value;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($value)
    {
        $this->id = $value;
    }

    public function getKey()
    {
        return $this->key;
    }

    public function setKey($value)
    {
        $this->key = $value;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}


/* View */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `View` (
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    created_by INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    updated_by INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `key` CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `value` JSON NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY PK_VIEW (`key`),
    UNIQUE KEY UQ_VIEW (id)
) CHARSET = latin1;

$entity = new View();
$entity->setCreatedBy(0);
$entity->setUpdatedBy(0);
$entity->setKey($messageId);
$entity->setValue($json);

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->merge($entity);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: so your 'key' is your primary key , but when you call a query you can have several records with the same 'key' how come so ?  can you explain more please.

Comment: @MoxGeek No, that's not what I meant. I have an external stream of objects coming in which may or not contain duplicates, and I'm trying to persist them to DB. In case of duplicates, I want to take the last one and save to DB. The duplicates may be interleaved with other distinct objects with unique keys. To clarify, both `id` and `key` are meant to be unique in DB.

Comment: so you have a steam of data comming to your webservice or api or whatever , and  wanna edit the record that you have alredy in your db with the last one recived from your api based on the 'key' , isn't ?

Comment: @MoxGeek Yes, but I also want to maintain an `id` column that is AI and unique

Comment: you can make a edit query based on the key not on the id, and then edit your record with all your incoming data , but if these data are so big you can queue it into redis or something.
what is the problem if you did edit the record based on key and keep your id as is it?

Comment: That would also work, yes, but I thought merge() based on PK would be faster. This is actually meant to be a Queue consumer. Amazon SQS is providing the incoming stream, hence the possibility of duplicates. Since I might be processing a large number of incoming objects, I was hoping to make this as efficient as possible. That's why I thought using the PK might be better.

Comment: i got your point, but i still think even if you did a merge it  will be kind of problematic in your cases. espcially if you have a big amount of data, cause performing any kind of operation at the database level will be slow with the time and size of your incoming data. 
a caching system will be good i guess in this case. i strongly think that queue ( in my opinion ) is the best solution that fit your need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217901/discussion-between-thejaka-maldeniya-and-moxgeek).